# How to cut or split the rect object into two or more while event is triggered using fabric JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, fabricjs

```js
(function() {
  var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("canvas");
  fabric.Object.prototype.transparentCorners = false;

  var rect = new fabric.Rect({
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    top: 100,
    left: 100,
    selectable:false,
    fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)'
  });

  canvas.add(rect);

  var timeoutTriggered = true;

  function stopDragging(element) {
    element.lockMovementX = true;
    element.lockMovementY = true;
  }

  function onMoving(e) {
    if (!timeoutTriggered) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        stopDragging(e.target);
      }, 500);
      timeoutTriggered = true;
    }
  }
  canvas.on({
    'object:moving': onMoving
  });
})();
```

```css
#canvas {
  border: 5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.11/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="500" width="500"></canvas>
```

[rect object](http://jsfiddle.net/a7mad24/aPLq5/)

While event is triggered created rect should be divided into two
equal parts.

I need to know whether it is possible or not to cut or split the rect object into two or more while event is triggered using fabric JavaScript.

```
<canvas ID="c" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c', { selection: false });

var rect, isDown, origX, origY;

canvas.on('mouse:down', function(o){
    isDown = true;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    origX = pointer.x;
    origY = pointer.y;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);
    rect = new fabric.Rect({
        left: origX,
        top: origY,
        originX: 'left',
        originY: 'top',
        width: pointer.x-origX,
        height: pointer.y-origY,
        angle: 0,
        fill: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
        transparentCorners: false
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(o){
    if (!isDown) return;
    var pointer = canvas.getPointer(o.e);

    if(origX>pointer.x){
        rect.set({ left: Math.abs(pointer.x) });
    }
    if(origY>pointer.y){
        rect.set({ top: Math.abs(pointer.y) });
    }

    rect.set({ width: Math.abs(origX - pointer.x) });
    rect.set({ height: Math.abs(origY - pointer.y) });


    canvas.renderAll();
});

canvas.on('mouse:up', function(o){
  isDown = false;
});
```

Comment: The question is interesting but not 100% clear. Maybe you could add an image to illustrate what you want to achieve.

Comment: Any further thoughts or is this question dead?

Comment: Above i have attached a snipppet.In the above snippet I want to cut rect area at any position inside rectangle using mouse pointer.

Comment: Above i have attached a snipppet.In the above snippet I want to cut rectangle area horizontally at any position inside rectangle using mouse pointer down.If it is archived, rect area will appear as two rect rectangle.

Comment: [Maybe you want something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/aPLq5/307/)? *drag* = solid rect; *ctrl-drag* - rect with vertical split; *alt-drag* - rect with horizontal split. Probably not exactly what you want but could form a basis.

Comment: yes this what I want! But Is this possible?

Comment: I'm sure that cutting the rect area "at any position" could be achieved but you would need to specify the desired user interaction that would control the position. The difficulty I foresee is how to control the rectangle's size and the position of the cut simultaneously.

Comment: I found time to put together [another demo of what's possible](http://jsfiddle.net/hwcbyhu2/4/) - instructions within.